# Data Workshop Import problems

Tags: excel, csv, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Recently, I was uploading a CSV file that was dropped from an Access database. During the conversion of the data I received messages that a month field was incorrect.
So, in Excel I converted the format of the data to `mm/dd/yyyy`.  Eventually all of the records loaded successfully.  But users noticed that dates formatted as `01/12/2017` in the Excel CSV file were displayed as `12/01/2017` once loaded via Data Workshop (Apex Product Build 5.0.4.00.12).
I worked with our DBA who advised me that the correct date in Apex should have been `01/12/2017`, not `12/01/2017`...

The DBA ended up uploading the data in Oracle directly.  I wasn't sure if I did something incorrectly, if it is a problem with the Data Workshop  or if there is a fix for the problem.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While importing through the data workshop you will be presented with the columns present in your import file and some of the sample data. You can then specify the format mask for columns such as dates or numbers. If you do not specify a mask the database NLS settings (or, the NLS settings which have been configured for apex during its post-installation tasks) will be used, which might not be what you want. In your case, if your data is being offered in `mm/dd/yyyy`, then specify this mask while importing.

Then again, while querying and not specifying the format mask, you will again see dates being formatted according to these NLS settings. Either know the mask or set it in your IDE, or perform a `to_char` conversion to be sure of the values.

Comment: Finally found the formatting area (right in front of my eyes) and it worked. Thank you again for helping me out